# Proving the orthogonality of curvature and unit tangent

Tags: orthogonality, curves

Consider the unit tangent $T = P'(t)/||P'(t)||$ and curvature $K = T'$ of a curve $P(t)$. The curvature being the derivative of the unit tangent by definition.

If I were to show that $K$ is orthogonal to $T$, would it be mathematically enough to show that

$2T * T' = 0$

derived from the fact that the dot product of T with itself is one. It is quite intuitive that if $2T$ is orthogonal to something then $T$ must be as well, but is that a solid proof? If not, then how would I show the orthogonality of K and T?

Answer (score 1):

A scalar multiple of a vector has the same direction as the unscaled vector when the scalar is positive, and opposite direction when the scalar is negative. So if $2T \cdot T' = 0$, then $2T$ and $T'$ are orthogonal - which means that $T$ and $T'$ are orthogonal by the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
that is correct.

Just divide by 2.

Comment: I see, I missed the easy part there. Additionally, does this mean that for the proof we don't even need the definition of the unit tangent as given in my question? I.e. do we not need to go through differentiating $P'(t)/||P'(t)||$ and doing the dot product of that and $T$ then?